# Returns True if two cells contains specific characters in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell A1: `K+`

Cell B1: `P(K, G, Y)`

I would like it to return true in C1 if  A1 contains any characters in B1. The current formula that I could think of is:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-2),B1))=LEFT(A1,1),"T","F")
```

I know the formula is wrong, however I am stuck in identifying the correct formula.

Comment: how about more sample data with expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this non-array formula,

```
=ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(1,-FIND(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1))),1),B1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an **array** formula:

```
=OR(IFERROR(FIND(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1))),1),$B1),FALSE))
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

For a normally entered formula, if you have the `AGGREGATE` function, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1))),1),$B1),1)>0,FALSE)
```

The formula is case-sensitive.  To make it case-insensitive, change `FIND` to `SEARCH`

[image]

Algorithm:

- Split `A1` into an array of one character elements:

  - `MID($A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A1))`
- Try to `FIND` each character in that array in B1

  - This will return an array of `#VALUE!` errors and digits depending on whether the character is found or not.
- `IFERROR` to return FALSE since `FIND` will return an error if it does not find the character.

  - Now we have an array of `{TRUE,FALSE}`
- `OR` will then return `TRUE` if any one of the characters is found, else `FALSE`

For the `AGGREGATE` function

- It will return the a number > 0 if `FIND` matches something in B1.

  - `AGGREGATE` can be set to ignore the errors
- Again, if nothing is found, then `AGGREGATE` will return an error, since there are not digits, and the `IFERROR` will convert that to `FALSE`